# Proxy cannot be cast to CLASS

Tags: spring, hibernate, casting

I'm using Spring for wiring dependencies specifically for DAO classes that use Hibernate, but I'm getting an exception that has me puzzled:

**$Proxy58 cannot be cast to UserDao**

My DAO is configured as follows:

```
<bean id="userDao" class="com.domain.app.dao.UserDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And I have an interface, abstract base class and a final implementation as follows.

Interface:

```
public interface Dao {
    public void save(Object object);
    public Object load(long id);
    public void delete(Object object);
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory);
}
```

Abstract Base Class:

```
public abstract class BaseDao implements Dao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void save(Object object) {
        PersistentEntity obj = (PersistentEntity) object;
        currentSession().saveOrUpdate(obj);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public abstract Object load(long id);

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(Object object) {
        // TODO: this method!
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

}
```

Implementation:

```
public class UserDao extends BaseDao implements Dao {

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public Object load(long id) {
        Object user = currentSession().get(User.class, id);
        return user;
    }

}
```

The following throws the exception mentioned above:

*UserDao dao = (UserDao) context.getBean("userDao");*

This, however, does not throw an exception:

*Dao dao = (Dao) context.getBean("userDao");*

If anyone can offer any assistance or guidance as to why this exception is happening, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$Proxy25 cannot be cast to my class spring framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702364/proxy25-cannot-be-cast-to-my-class-spring-framework)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Spring uses [JDK dynamic proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) by default (`$Proxy58` is one of them), that can only proxy interfaces. This means that the dynamically created type `$Proxy58` will implement one or more of the interfaces implemented by the wrapped/target class (`UserDao`), but it won't be an actual subclass of it. That's basically why you can cast the `userDao` bean to the `Dao` *interface*, but not to the `UserDao` *class*.

You can use `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>` to instruct Spring to use CGLIB proxies that are actual subclasses of the proxied class, but I think it's better practice to program against interfaces. If you need to access some methods from the proxied class which are not declared in one of it's interfaces, you should ask yourself first, why this is the case?
(Also, in your code above there are no new methods introduced in `UserDao`, so there is no point in casting the bean to this concrete implementation type anyway.)

See more about different proxying mechanisms in the official [Spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying).

Comment: Extremely helpful for future reference.  Thanks @zagyi for the insight!

Comment: Helpful for understanding Guice too.

Comment: "...you should ask yourself first, why this is the case?" - one example is to test internal methods in a unit test. I'd like to test a specific implementation, not the interface.
Anyway, great answer!

Answer (score 11):

I was writing unit tests and needed to be able to stub out the DAOs for some calls.
Per This guys post:
http://www.techper.net/2009/06/05/how-to-acess-target-object-behind-a-spring-proxy/
I used his method provided:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
protected <T> T getTargetObject(Object proxy, Class<T> targetClass) throws Exception {
  if (AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(proxy)) {
    return (T) ((Advised)proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget();
  } else {
    return (T) proxy; // expected to be cglib proxy then, which is simply a specialized class
  }
}
```

Then you can easily call it with the proxy and get the object behind the proxy and manipulate the objects in it directly as needed.